# Offset selenium clicks using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently having selenium find an xpath and clicking on it. However, there's another picture on top of the element, so I would need to click slightly higher or lower. Is there a way to do this using python? (I’m running it on a simple illustration software. And I just need to select the background)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """myxpath"""))).click()
```

Error: is not clickable at point (815, 406). Other element would receive the click:

So instead of clicking (815,406), id like the system to click (200,200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `ActionChains`. You need to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Then, you can use the following method

```
def click_element_with_offset(self, xpath : str, xAxis : int, yAxis: int):
        actionChain = ActionChains(self.driver)
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        actionChain.move_to_element_with_offset(element, xAxis, yAxis).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Element is overlaying try something like this to directly click on the element.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """myxpath""")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```